# How may I see all the pages on my wordpress website and see when they were created?

Tags: seo, urls

My wordpress website has been hacked with malware and it has generated unwanted spam pages on my website without me knowing. I need to remove the spam pages. Is there a way to see a comprehensive list of all the pages under my domain so I can weed out the spam pages? Also is there a way to see the date in which pages are created?

Comment: Any reason not to use the pages menu? You can see the creation date and sort the pages based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Himads comment. I'm assuming you are talking about the wordpress specific term pages.

> A Page should not be confused with the time-oriented objects called Posts, nor should a WordPress Page be confused with the word “page” referring to any web page or HTML document on the Web.

Begin by logging into the administration area, or the back end, of your website. Visit your site’s login page by placing wp-admin after your domain name (e.g., http://example.com/wp-admin)

Click on the Pages link in the sidebar on the left.
[image: administration area or back end]

The All Pages Screen  opens. You can sort the pages by date by clicking on Date. You can delete pages by checking a pages checkbox and clicking on trash in the context menu that opens.
[image]

Administration area: https://wordpress.org/support/article/first-steps-with-wordpress/#log-in
All Pages screen: https://wordpress.org/support/article/pages-screen/